# How do I publish Boost unit tests with Jenkins pipeline and xUnit plugin

Tags: unit-testing, jenkins, boost, continuous-integration, xunit

I'm in the process of migrating our old Jenkins build to a declarative pipeline.  We use the xUnit plugin to publish unit tests and for JUnit the following works just fine:

```
step([$class: 'XUnitBuilder',
      thresholds: [[$class: 'FailedThreshold', unstableThreshold: '1']],
      tools: [[$class: 'JUnitType', pattern: '**/surefire-reports/*.xml'],
              [$class: 'JUnitType', pattern: '**/generatedJUnitFiles/JUnit/*.xml'],]
     ])
```

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to publish our boost tests.  Is there a `BoostType` similar to `JUnitType`, or are boost tests not supported yet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer turned out to be BoostTestJunitHudsonTestType.  This is the code:

```
step([$class: 'XUnitBuilder',
            thresholds: [[$class: 'FailedThreshold', unstableThreshold: '1']],
            tools: [[$class: 'JUnitType', pattern: '**/surefire-reports/*.xml'],
                    [$class: 'JUnitType', pattern: '**/generatedJUnitFiles/JUnit/*.xml'],
                    [$class: 'BoostTestJunitHudsonTestType', pattern: '**/*_results.xml'],
                     ]])
```

Comment: Would you be kind enough to point to some documentation that explains this `step()` command, and its syntax? I have found nothing.

Answer (score 11):

The [new xunit Plugin syntax](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin) is a bit lighter and more readable:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test'){
            steps {
                sh "run_tests.bash"
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always{
            xunit (
                thresholds: [ skipped(failureThreshold: '0'), failed(failureThreshold: '0') ],
                tools: [
                    JUnit(pattern: '**/surefire-reports/*.xml'),
                    JUnit(pattern: '**/generatedJUnitFiles/JUnit/*.xml'),
                    BoostTest(pattern: '**/*_results.xml')]
            )
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

There's a class [`BoostTest`](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/xunit/index.html?org/jenkinsci/plugins/xunit/types/BoostTest.html) in Jenkins' [xUnit Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/xUnit+Plugin).

Comment: Thanks for the help.  It's actually BoostTestJunitHudsonTestType.